# Coloring excel table according to highest values VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table in excel and I want to go over each row and color the top two highest values in each row.
I'm trying to use VBA, I dont want to use conditional formatting.
this is what I wrote:

```
Sub top_two()
Sheets("sheet1").Select
Dim all_rows As Range
Set all_rows = Range("C6:K8")
Dim c As Range
For Each c In all_rows.Rows
    For Each d In c.Cells
        If d = WorksheetFunction.Large(c, 1) Or c = WorksheetFunction.Large(c, 2) Then
            d.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        End If
    Next
Next
End sub()
```

the table is Range("C6:K8"), it has 3 rows now. For some reason that doesn't work. Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple minor mistakes in your code:

1. You never declared `Dim d as Range`.
2. `c = WorksheetFunction...` should actually be `d = WorksheetFunction...`

I think if you fix those two errors, it will work.

One other detail - there should be no parentheses after `End Sub`.

Comment: Thank you, It was the second mistake I wrote c instead of d. I didn't declared d as Range but it works without it, don't know why but it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

1. What exactly does it do? The best would be to run the VBA script in debug mode step after step and see what it does on every iteration.
2. It does not seem terribly efficient to call `WorksheetFunction.Large` twice when you iterate over every cell (what if you have thousands of these cells?). I think you should store these values to variables like `max` and `2ndmax` and use them instead. Btw what if there are largest values like 1000,1000,900 or 1000,100,1000 how do you want your macro to handle that? You will have more than two cells colored.
3. I dont see the Range type variable d declared there. Not sure if this might cause the problem.

4.I would avoid using "select" at all. You can reference the Range anywhere without the need to select the particular worksheet.